# Only First Element shows up in Populating list from Async Task

Tags: java, android, mysql, listview, arraylist

Hello i am trying to build a listview and populate it from values in `Mysql` database. The list with SimpleAdapter works but i decided to change the listview and use my own adapter that extends ArrayAdapter and create my own listItem and not the HashMap. The code is below

```
public void ListDrawer() {
        customList = new ArrayList<StockList>();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("metoxes");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
                String price = jsonChildNode.optString("price");
                String price1 = jsonChildNode.optString("price1");
                String price2 = jsonChildNode.optString("price2");
                String price3 = jsonChildNode.optString("price3");
                String price4 = jsonChildNode.optString("price4");
                String price5 = jsonChildNode.optString("price5");
                String price6 = jsonChildNode.optString("price6");
                String price7 = jsonChildNode.optString("price7");
                String price8 = jsonChildNode.optString("price8");
                String price9 = jsonChildNode.optString("price9");
                String price10 = jsonChildNode.optString("price10");
                String price11 = jsonChildNode.optString("price11");
                String price12 = jsonChildNode.optString("price12");
                String price13 = jsonChildNode.optString("price13");
                String price14 = jsonChildNode.optString("price14");
                String price15 = jsonChildNode.optString("price15");
                String image = jsonChildNode.optString("image");
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmapFromUrl(image);

                StockList item = new StockList(name, price, bmp);
                customList.add(item);

//                customList.add(createStockList(name, price, price1, price2,
//                        price3, price4, price5, price6, price7, price8, price9,
//                        price10, price11, price12, price13, price14, price15));



            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(ListLoaderActivity.this,
                    RefreshActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            ListLoaderActivity.this.finish();
        }

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new MyStocksAdapter(ListLoaderActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, customList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        startList.setAdapter(adapter);

//        String[] from = {"name", "price"};
//        int[] to = {R.id.stock_name, R.id.stock_price};
//        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, customList,
//                R.layout.list_item, from, to);


    }

    /*public HashMap<String, String> createStockList(String name, String price,
                                                   String price1, String price2, String price3, String price4,
                                                   String price5, String price6, String price7, String price8,
                                                   String price9, String price10, String price11, String price12,
                                                   String price13, String price14, String price15) {
        HashMap<String, String> stockNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
        stockNameNo.put("name", name);
        stockNameNo.put("price", price);
        stockNameNo.put("price1", price1);
        stockNameNo.put("price2", price2);
        stockNameNo.put("price3", price3);
        stockNameNo.put("price4", price4);
        stockNameNo.put("price5", price5);
        stockNameNo.put("price6", price6);
        stockNameNo.put("price7", price7);
        stockNameNo.put("price8", price8);
        stockNameNo.put("price9", price9);
        stockNameNo.put("price10", price10);
        stockNameNo.put("price11", price11);
        stockNameNo.put("price12", price12);
        stockNameNo.put("price13", price13);
        stockNameNo.put("price14", price14);
        stockNameNo.put("price15", price15);
        return stockNameNo;
    }*/
```

My Custom List Item:

```
public class StockList {

    private String stockCurrentName;
    private String stockCurrentPrice;
    private Bitmap stockImage;

    public StockList(String stockCurrentName, String stockCurrentPrice, Bitmap stockImage) {
        this.stockCurrentName = stockCurrentName;
        this.stockCurrentPrice = stockCurrentPrice;
        this.stockImage = stockImage;
    }

    public String getStockCurrentName() {
        return stockCurrentName;
    }

    public void setStockCurrentName(String stockCurrentName) {
        this.stockCurrentName = stockCurrentName;
    }

    public String getStockCurrentPrice() {
        return stockCurrentPrice;
    }

    public void setStockCurrentPrice(String stockCurrentPrice) {
        this.stockCurrentPrice = stockCurrentPrice;
    }

    public Bitmap getStockImage() {
        return stockImage;
    }

    public void setStockImage(Bitmap stockImage) {
        this.stockImage = stockImage;
    }
}
```

My Custom Adapter

```
public class MyStocksAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StockList>{
    private View stockView;
    private List<StockList> stocksList;
    private RoundImage roundedImage;

    public MyStocksAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<StockList> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(stockView == null){
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            stockView = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            StockList current = getItem(position);

            if(current != null){
                TextView stockName = (TextView)stockView.findViewById(R.id.stock_name);
                stockName.setText(current.getStockCurrentName());


                TextView stockPrice = (TextView)stockView.findViewById(R.id.stock_price);
                stockPrice.setText(current.getStockCurrentPrice());

                ImageView stockImage = (ImageView)stockView.findViewById(R.id.imagestartinglist);
                stockImage.setImageBitmap(current.getStockImage());
            }


        }
        return stockView;

    }
}
```

The xml layout i use for every list row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#ccc"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stock_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fake_name_day"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fake_name_day"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stock_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fake_name_day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stock_name"
        android:text="@string/current_price"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/stock_name"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stock_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagestartinglist"
        android:text="@string/stock_name"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagestartinglist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_stock_custom_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The thing is that everything works but it only displays the 1st item from the database and i dont know why since i add the items inside the for loop.

Any ideas???

Comment: I don't know if it is a typo or you forgot to initialize `stocksList` in the adapter constructor to be equal to `objects`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are using same object `stockView` to check for null every time. When first item is rendered it's not null so every time same object is used.

Use this...

```
public class MyStocksAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StockList>{
private List<StockList> stocksList;
private RoundImage roundedImage;

public MyStocksAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<StockList> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View stockView = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        StockList current = getItem(position);

        if(current != null){
            TextView stockName = (TextView)stockView.findViewById(R.id.stock_name);
            stockName.setText(current.getStockCurrentName());


            TextView stockPrice = (TextView)stockView.findViewById(R.id.stock_price);
            stockPrice.setText(current.getStockCurrentPrice());

            ImageView stockImage = (ImageView)stockView.findViewById(R.id.imagestartinglist);
            stockImage.setImageBitmap(current.getStockImage());
        }
    return stockView;
}
}
```

Comment: It happens with everyone...  :D

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is the `stockView` is not null after the second time , you can make sure of that by debugging the `getView` method

so the solution for that is

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(stockView == null){
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        stockView = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);


    }
    StockList current = getItem(position);

    if(current != null){
         TextView stockName = (TextView)stockView.findViewById(R.id.stock_name);
         stockName.setText(current.getStockCurrentName());

         TextView stockPrice = (TextView)stockView.findViewById(R.id.stock_price);
         stockPrice.setText(current.getStockCurrentPrice());

         ImageView stockImage = (ImageView)stockView.findViewById(R.id.imagestartinglist);
            stockImage.setImageBitmap(current.getStockImage());
        }


    return stockView;

}
```